# Configure NGINX for NodeJS Site on Windows Server 2012

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have looked through numerous NGINX configuration questions but they all seem to deal with multiple ports.  What I am attempting is (apparently) very simple but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I have a working NodeJS application running on Windows Server 2012 R2.  It hosts a React site and uses SSO authentication, which works correctly.

I am now trying to configure this for production use running on Port 80.  Everything I have read says to use NGINX with a simple redirect configuration.  Unfortunately (after several restarts and changes in configuration to resolve error messages) now I am receiving 404 errors on port 80.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    # include mime.types;
    # default_type application/octet-stream;
    # sendfile on;
    # keepalive_timeout 65;
    # gzip on;
    server {
        listen 80;
        
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
            # proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 240s;
        }
    }
}
```

I have never used NGINX before and am very weak in http configuration so cannot determine where the fault lies.

Comment: check NGINX error log

Comment: don't you miss the `server_name` in `server`?

Comment: is that NodeJS application running on port 9000?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira The error log is showing nothing since I have come up with this final configuration.  The Node application is indeed running on port 9000 and there is no indication that server_name is required, but I will add it in just in case.

Comment: Adding server_name localhost; didn't seem to make any difference.  What I read says that is used to define a server block, which I assume means running multiple servers simultaneously.

Comment: `server_name` is not localhost but the host of the domain you're using for the app, for example `example.com`. If you're running the app in a OS with UI, check your browser at `http://localhost:9000` to be sure the NodeJS app is running as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  Rather than using NGINX I was able to run Node through PM2 using elevated privileges on port 80.  Then I resolved the CORS issue by remove 'http://localhost' from all my api fetch calls.  Once this was done everything worked correctly as I had hoped.